# ssh login causes repeating characters in my zsh

Tags: ssh, zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh, iterm

I am on a Mac using iTerm2 and zsh v5.7.1. When I login from my local computer to the remote computer using 'ssh', most of the characters are repeated at the prompt as I type. Clearing the line with Ctrl-L displays the correctly typed input. I am reasonably sure this is an issue of my prompt using UTF-8 and Esc characters. If I immediately run 'bash' after logging in, I have access to a prompt without special characters, and thus no repeating characters. My standard prompt is Powerlevel10K.
TTY=/dev/ttys000
TERM=xterm-256color-italic

Example:

> buckley@dusky   ~  eecechecho ""EExxrrtr x xttrraa  cchhaaaa
>   arraaccttrt teerrss"  buckley@dusky   ~  echo "Extra characters"

I obviously do not see these extra characters when I am using that 'remote' computer locally, but only when I 'ssh' into it.

I am hoping someone can point me to the offending file or command, such that 'ssh' properly recognizes the remote login environment and prompt.

Comment: This [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90772/first-characters-of-the-command-repeated-in-the-display-when-completing) might explain the problem, if it's indeed the prompt.

Comment: Partially resolved. The issue was the "TERM=xterm-256color-italic" is not working when trying to remote in with 'ssh' even though my login is properly using TERM=xterm-256color-italic when I am local on that computer.
I need to figure out how to add this italic flavor of TERM to the system. 
For now, I am using the following (alias'd) command to ssh in: "TERM=xterm-256color ssh username@remotehost"

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this strange behaviour, you have to set `LC_ALL` env variable on the remote machine to the same value as in your local machine. To check what is your `LC_ALL` set to, type on the local machine:

```
echo $LC_ALL
```

In my case my system returned `C.UTF-8`. To set the variable for single ssh session only, just type in the remote session:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

However, if you want this to be done once for all, add this^ line somewhere in the `.zshrc` file on the remote machine.

If for any reason it will still not help, try to experiment with `LANG` and `LC_CTYPE` also setting this to the same value as `LS_ALL`. In my case:

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Your prompt contains Unicode characters but `LC_CTYPE` on the remote machine is not UTF-8. You can confirm this by typing `locale | grep LC_CTYPE`.

To fix this, you first need to ensure the desired locale is installed on the remote machine. Type `locale -a` to see the list of installed locales. If the locale you want (which is probably the same locale you are using on your local machine) is missing, you need to install it. The specific command to do so depends on your the OS and distribution of the remote machine.

Then you either need to instruct sshd to accept locale environment variables from clients (`man sshd_config` and search for `AcceptEnv`) or manually set `LANGUAGE` in `~/.zshrc` of the remote machine.